# How to Hide port 8080?

Tags: apache, redirect, jboss, jboss7.x

How I can hide the port 8080 from the address bar?
when I call my sub.domain.com I get nothing but when I call my sub.domain.com:8008 I get the application!
I am using apache2 and jboss 7

Thanks

```
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName sub.domain.com
ServerAlias sub.domain.com
<Location /myapp>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp
</Location>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.asp index.aspx index.jsp index.jspa index.shtml index.shtm
</virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 2):

just and copy and past this config to your sites-enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
    # List of application servers:
    # Usage:
    # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # Example:
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/

    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the port from address bar, try to start sever using port 80 , you can change the stanalone.xml file

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="80"/>
```

Comment: it's default port, when trying to access url without port number its automatically take port number 80